# php arrayObj insensitive to undegined index

Tags: php

How to make `ArrayObj` in insensitive to undefined index, I sometimes need use undefined index example in logging

```
$this->log['some']['other']['info']++
```

Here is my try:

```
class arrayInSensitive extends \arrayObject{

    var $data = array();

    public function offsetGet($name) {
        if(!array_key_exists($name,$this->data)) $this->data[$name]=new arrayInSensitive();

        return $this->data[$name];
    }
    public function offsetSet($name, $value) {
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }
    public function offsetExists($name) {
        return (array_key_exists($name,$this->data));
    }
    public function offsetUnset($name) {
        unset($this->data[$name]);
    }

}
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just force a specific case whenever you reference the index value

```
class arrayInSensitive extends \arrayObject{

    var $data = array();

    public function offsetGet($name) {
        if(!array_key_exists(strtolower($name),$this->data)) $this->data[strtolower($name)]=new arrayInSensitive();

        return $this->data[strtolower($name)];
    }
    public function offsetSet($name, $value) {
        $this->data[strtolower($name)] = $value;
    }
    public function offsetExists($name) {
        return (array_key_exists(strtolower($name),$this->data));
    }
    public function offsetUnset($name) {
        unset($this->data[strtolower($name)]);
    }

}
```